# Which is the best choice for windows app SQL Server Express / SQLite / SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

> I know this cloud be duplicate of many question but again the answer is not straight forward.

I know it depends upon usage and functionality of windows application

But as SQL Server CE (compact edition) does not have any features like views, stored procedures , function etc , It is light weighted.

> please guid me to choose which should I used among SQL Server Express / SQLite / SQL Server CE?

I have already gone through all procs and cons still need a single line answer :(

> I'm working on windows application which is an desktop app of paper setter
>   it will set question paper.

Exactly depending upon requirement I need to decide but I'm worried about the space and performance. if I choose SQL express then it might take a long time depending upon computer config. My win app will related with papers which includes audio and video sets also

for this app which could be the best to use please guide.

Comment: This is not a suitable question as SO is not a recommendation engine. You haven't stated all the parameters of your use cases so noone can know what's best except you as the designer. Vote to close.

Comment: @PreetSangha yes exactly depending upon requirement I need to decide but I'm worried about the space and performance.
if I choose SQL express then it might take a long time depending upon computer config.

My win app will related with papers which includes audio and video sets aslo

Comment: So you need do proper design around the constraints that you have. This might be reading and prototyping. It's not a question that someone who knows nothing about your use cases can ever answer except to provide a 'finger in the air' pontificate. Consider this - what if I said 'You need SQL Server Express' because in my designs its' the only thing that is needed. How does that help you? To do proper design you really need to consider *your* use cases*. You've not even stated them - so possibly this is something you need to define first before even considering what DB you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows app, if you want to use store procedure and views kind of things then you must need to use SQL Express, but if your database is small and you can manage through just select statements and insert / update statements then you need to use sqllite for small db purpose.

So based on your requirement you need to take a decision.

Comment: I can't see how you can say SQL Lite is what the OP should use if he doesn't need SPs you don't know what the requirements are. Why is CE not useful? It's only an opinion not really an answer.

Comment: @PreetSangha yes exactly depending upon requirement I need to decide but I'm worried about the space and performance. if I choose SQL express then it might take a long time depending upon computer config. My win app will related with papers which includes audio and video sets aslo

Comment: Hey, if your app contains big data and like audio / video kind of things then you must need to use express so you can get better options on db side and performance good.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure, but this will help u.

```
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone
```